# How to make the iframe shrank and row according to the content size?

Tags: html, css

i have an iframe and need it ti shrank and grow according to the contents height in the run time

```
<iframe src='demo-frame.php' >Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
```

any help?

Comment: Can you add more description to your problem? Do you mean the content inside the iframe is positioned in the middle of the iframe and not at the top?

Comment: thanks Ryano for your care, actually i get it and the question is changed to be more clear , i need to make it shrank and grow easly in run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following with some jQuery...

```
$('#iframeID').load(function () {
    $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
    $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
});
```